# Why can't I add <some list>.append to a python set?

Tags: python, set

Why is it that I can add normal callables and methods to a set, but not `<some list>.append` (for instance)?

For Example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(l.append)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> type(l.append)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(map)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> s.add(map)
>>> def func(): print 'func'
... 
>>> s.add(func)
>>> print s
set([<built-in function map>, <function func at 0x10a659758>])
```

Edit: I noticed that `l.append.__hash__()` also gives this error

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? o_O

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm writing tests using twisted.trial. I have an event bus system that registers callbacks for an event (designated by a string) and stores the callbacks in a set to prevent duplicates. This particular callback is just a wrapper around results_list.append so I was trying to register that directly as a callback. The test fires an event, and checks results_list to see if it contains data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot add `list`s to a set because lists are mutable. Only immutable objects can be added to sets.

`l.append` is an instance method. You can think of it as if it were the tuple `(l, list.append)` — that is, it's the list.append() method tied to the particular list `l`. The list.append() method is immutable but `l` is not. So while you can add `list.append` to the set you can't add `l.append`.

This works:

```
>>> s.add(list.append)
```

This does not work:

```
>>> s.add((l, list.append))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: I stand corrected.  Not surprising I suppose, ... The surprising thing is that I was going through life always thinking that all tuples were hashable :)

Comment: The behavior makes sense.  Initially I thought you could fall back on object ID's, but that doesn't work because what do you do when you try to index your dictionary with a different (equivalent) tuple:  `d[(500,600)] = ...`.  Since the ID's are different, that common use case would fail.  The only way to hash the tuple reliably is to hash each element.  Very interesting.

Comment: Update: Not sure what underlying functionality was changed, but this works in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 3):

You're not trying to add `list.append`.  You're trying to add `l.append` which is an instance method, not a class method.  `list` instances aren't hashable, and apparently their methods aren't hashable either.

Think of it this way.  You have 2 lists:

```
lfoo = []
lbar = []
```

Now you want to add their respective appends to your set:

```
s = set()
s.add(lfoo.append)
s.add(lbar.append)
```

Now when you do the hash lookup for the set, you can't just rely on the function portion of the instance method.  Indeed, `lfoo` and `lbar` ultimately use the same function (`list.append`).  So that isn't a unique hash.  The way you make it unique is by attaching it to an instance.  However, the instance doesn't support hashing, so the set has no way of telling the difference between `lfoo.append` and `lbar.append`.

Comment: Thanks, updated the question to refer to <some list>.append, not list.append

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `list` objects aren't hashable. I suspect that when you hash an instance method, it incorporates the hash of the instance its bound to. As such, you get the `TypeError`.